# How to get year and month of date

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]i have 2 form, form1 contains an input date and a button validate, i want when i click on button validate the year of the date show in the cells year and month of the date show in the cells of months .
NB:button validate display form2 and hide form1.
button validate display form2 and hide form1

```
<div id="form1">
  <div class="form-group">    
     <label>Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="datePicker" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
//form 2
<div id="form2">
    <h4>DATE : <span id="dateE"></span></h4>

  <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>matricule</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>month</th>
    <th>salary</th>
    <th>number day</th>
    <th>premium</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td>7000</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
  <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">Pointage men</button>
</div>
```

css code to hide form2

```
    <style>
    #form2{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

code jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $('#datePicker').val(today);
});
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#hide").click(function(){
            let valu = $('#datePicker').val();
             $('#dateE').text(valu);
             $('.year').val(valu);
             $('.month').val(valu);

            $("#form1").hide();
            $("#form2").show();
          });
 });
```

Comment: Please make sure your example is minimal, to allow others to read your code thoroughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.  First is that you are setting the `.val()` of a hidden input field, not setting the contents of the `<td>` surrounding it.  And secondly, you're setting the value of that field as the full date.

There are a couple ways you can do this. You could just split the date string on '-', and put the values in, or you can create a date object and get the year and month from it.

Then you can put the values into the `<td>` fields.  If you still need the hidden inputs, you can still add the value to them the way that you are currently doing it.

I have included a working snippet that you can run below.

Explanation:

```
let valu = $('#datePicker').val();
let selectedDate = new Date(valu); // This makes a new Date object from the selected date
var selectedYear = selectedDate.getFullYear(); // This grabs the year from that date
var selectedMonth = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1; // This grabs the month from that date.  We add 1, because getMonth is zero based, so January is 0.
```

So now we have two new variables, selectedYear and selectedMonth with the appropriate values, and then:

```
$('.year').val(selectedYear).parent().prepend(selectedYear);
$('.month').val(selectedMonth).parent().prepend(selectedMonth);
```

This section first sets the year and month values in the hidden input fields, and then prepends the text into the `.parent()` element of the hidden input, which in this case is the `<td>`

So now you have the text in the table, and the proper values in the hidden input elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $('#datePicker').val(today);
});
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#hide").click(function(){
            let valu = $('#datePicker').val();
            let selectedDate = new Date(valu);
            var selectedYear = selectedDate.getFullYear();
            var selectedMonth = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
             $('#dateE').text(valu);
             $('.year').val(selectedYear).parent().prepend(selectedYear);
             $('.month').val(selectedMonth).parent().prepend(selectedMonth);

            $("#form1").hide();
            $("#form2").show();
          });
 });
```

```css
#form2{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form1">
  <div class="form-group">    
     <label>Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="datePicker" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
//form 2
<div id="form2">
    <h4>DATE : <span id="dateE"></span></h4>

  <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>matricule</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>month</th>
    <th>salary</th>
    <th>number day</th>
    <th>premium</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" ></td>
    <td>7000</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
  <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">Pointage men</button>
</div>
```